# Jest gets undefined tag element

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I got the below code:

```html
const Footer = () => (
  <footer>
    <div className="logo">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/noviosparis/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img src="/assets/images/Instagram.svg" alt="Instagram" className='logo-social' />
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
)
```

```js
describe('<Footer />', () => {
  test('render component without crashing', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Footer />);

    expect(component.find(Footer)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  });
});
```

But i got the below error : `"<footer>"` is undefined, footer is a tag so i don't know what to do

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Need more details.

Comment: the problem is, I Got My Component called Footer but inside has tag a element called <footer>, and so the test tell me footer is undefined

Comment: You need to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)